# Changing PHP $_SERVER['HTTP_CONNECTION'] value

Tags: php, apache

One of my server has `$_SERVER['HTTP_CONNECTION']` is set to `close` need to set it to `keep-alive` in my phpinfo() any idea where to change that?

Apache config has

```
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 100
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_CONNECTION']` is the value of the HTTP `Connection` header **sent as part of the request by the client**. It is not a server setting. You cannot change it and you cannot force the client to send another value in that header. It's up to the client.

Comment: On another server of mine its set to $_SERVER['HTTP_CONNECTION'] = "keep-alive" in my phpinfo

Comment: What does that mean? It's still a value sent by the client. You're probably just seeing the same value as output by `$_SERVER`.

Comment: When i do phpinfo() on two different servers. Apache Environmental variable HTTP_CONNECTION for one of the server is close and one of the server is keep-alive. How does that vary?

Comment: Not sure. Inspect your traffic in detail, who is sending what header. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

Answer (score 0):

Contents of the Connection: header from the current request, if there is one.