# How to changes status of 'SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]' in localhost wamp and on any server

Tags: php, apache, server, xampp, wamp

[image]

I want to change the 'SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]' status keep-alive to close.

in wamp -> httpd-default.conf its show 
KeepAlive On

I already try to 'KeepAlive Off' but it doesn't works.
I want to set it off.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override Apache keep-alive header using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308404/how-to-override-apache-keep-alive-header-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible:

> $_SERVER['HTTP_CONNECTION'] is the value of the HTTP Connection header
>   sent as part of the request by the client. It is not a server setting.
>   You cannot change it and you cannot force the client to send another
>   value in that header. It's up to the client.

[Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242322/changing-php-serverhttp-connection-value)